# Ссылка в Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

В контролере создаю ссылку

```
$link = "https://translate.google.com";
```

Вывожу в файле view

```
Ссылка на сайт <a href="<?php echo $link ;?>">Link</a>
```

> Получаю в итоге результат
>   http://moisait.ru/controller/translate.google.com

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: Опечатка в вопросе. Исправил.

Answer (score 0):

`<?= anchor($link, 'Link') ?>`

Советую читать документацию перед тем, как задавать вопрос:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

P.S. Не используйте двойные кавычки, когда в них нет надобности:

`$link = 'https://translate.google.com';`